# Unity3d error when exporting app to phone

Tags: unity-game-engine

When developing an app in Unity 3d I was running into this error once and a while:

INSTALL_FAILED_MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE

Turns out if you run out of space on your phone, you'll get that error.

Answer (score 0):

Get a micro SD and move as many apps onto there as possible or delete apps from your phone memory.